# Social share button that contain # hashtag in the URL

Tags: php, share, linkedin-api

I am guessing that it is conflicting because of the "#" character in PHP or something?

Ex: `domain.com/#hero`

LinkedIn:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=domain.com/#hero&title=This%20is%20a%20title&summary=summary%20goes%20here&source=">/a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using URL encoding?
Try to use %23 in place of the hash in the href

Comment: What if you prefixedthe url with http://?  The example linkedin gives includes that.  Also looking at their documentation, the hash may be actually used by their API for something and so that could also be the reason it is stripping it.

Comment: Meaning that LinkedIn doesn't make this possible? Thank you!

Comment: For all intents and purposes it seems like it.  Which is odd since it uses #tags a lot for it's method of filtering information.   If i were you, check their API information and you may have another way of doing it.